# Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone not installing

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2010

I have download and installed Visual Studio 2010 RC and I want to develop for the new Windows Phone 7. But when I run the vm_web.exe (that IS the name of the exe file, isn't it?), It still says that I haven't installed Silverlight 4.0 SDK, BUT I have installed the Silverlight SDK. In my control panel's menu, it says I have installed "Microsoft Silverlight 4 Beta SDK".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Install Visual Studio 2010 RC Ultimate. Then install Express edition for Windows Phone:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2338b5d1-79d8-46af-b828-380b0f854203&displaylang=en

You will then be able to launch VS 2010 Ultimate and create Windows Phone projects. Currently There isn't a seperate install of the tools for VS2010 RC that dosen't require you to install the express edition.

Answer (score 1):

I think Release Candidate ver. not supporting Windows Phone Development. Express version of VS 2008 not supporting Windows Phone development too (and there is a same issue about installed SDK).